# how to set onload event for ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to insert javascript in my document by another javascript
I have a code:

```
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') proceed();
    } //this for IE but it doesn't work even for IE8
    script.onload = proceed; //this is for other browsers
```

so, how can I make it work for IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is something missing in your code. Namely actually appending the created script tag to the document.

Something like:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

After the lines of your script.

You can find this script hosted at http://ikanobori.jp/examples/loading-external-javascript/ where http://ikanobori.jp/examples/loading-external-javascript/one.js is the first file and http://ikanobori.jp/examples/loading-external-javascript/two.js is the dynamically loaded file.

I have verified this to work in Internet Explorer 8 but do not have lower versions available her.

Comment: as I already said the whole code works nice for Firefox, Chrome,... so all the append procedures are present, anyway thaks for your answer!

Comment: var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

Comment: @Bakudan, thank you.
@tsds, I have taken the liberty to host my code for you: http://ikanobori.jp/examples/loading-external-javascript/ I just verified that this *does* work in Internet Explorer. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I want to implement some function from the loaded js, here is an example  http://ocvs.ru - it works in almost all browsers except IE

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this to see if you ever get a complete

```
script.onreadystatechange = function () {
    document.title=this.readyState + ' - ' + new Date();
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') start();
}
```

Comment: it works, nevertheless the function in the script haven't started (i've added your modification into the example site code)

Comment: @tsds you mean you DO get complete in the title?